# Facing issue with sql query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT d.id,d.name,ds.booking_id 
FROM `driver_details` d 
JOIN driver_status ds on d.id=ds.driver_id 
WHERE ds.driver_flag=3 and ds.end_time  LIKE '2019-12-13%'
GROUP BY d.id desc
```

All are working fine except group by when i try groupby its showing this error

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc LIMIT 0, 1000' at line 4

Comment: `GROUP BY d.id desc` <--- `desc` is used for `ORDER BY`, not `GROUP BY`

Comment: (although once upon a time, it could be used with GROUP BY)

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is NEVER appropriate.

Comment: Maybe did you mean `GROUP BY d.id ORDER BY d.id desc`?

Comment: @user2342558 No, because that would return an indeterminate result.